# Declaring a knockout computed observable in typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I am new to typescript and would like to combine it with the goodness of knockout. I have a computed observable, which currently works, but want to know is this the right way about it or is there a better way.

I am using the [knockout definition file from nu-get](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). In it there are 4 KnockoutComputed(x) definitions.

1. KnockoutComputed
2. KnockoutComputedDefine
3. KnockoutComputedFunctions
4. KnockoutComputedStatic

I like the {} method of declaring observable's and would like to keep this. So long story short is this the correct method of declaring observables or is there an alternate way (maybe with intlisense in the function)

I am using the first like so:

```
class PersonViewModel {
    public firstname: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public lastname: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public fullname: KnockoutComputed<string>;
    constructor() {
        this.firstname = ko.observable('');
        this.lastname = ko.observable('');
        this.fullname = ko.computed({
            owner: this,
            read: function () {
                return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

with the html snippet of:

```
<h2>Type Script and Knockout.</h2>
<input data-bind="value: firstname" />
<input data-bind="value: lastname" />
<div data-bind="text: fullname"></div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Recommendation is to use arrow functions for computed. It will give you the desired intellisence as well:

```
this.fullname = ko.computed({
        owner: this,
        read:  () => {
            return this.firstname() + " " + this.lastname();
        }
    });
```

Basically that captures `this` using closure so it doesn't matter who calls back the function. `this` will continue to mean `PersonViewModel` instead of `any` . More : http://basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/this

Try the intellisense in [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20var%20ko:any;%0A%0Aclass%20PersonViewModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20firstname:%20any;%0A%20%20%20%20lastname:%20any;%0A%20%20%20%20fullname:%20any;%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.firstname%20=%20ko.observable%28%27%27%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.lastname%20=%20ko.observable%28%27%27%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fullname%20=%20ko.computed%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20owner:%20this,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20read:%20%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.firstname%20+%20%22%20%22%20+%20this.lastname%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D). You should get intellisense when you press `this.`

Comment: hey that's cool and also the website you sent. There is still no intelisense in visaul stuidio. Am i just going to have to suck it up and deal.

Comment: You should definitely get intellisense. Try the playground link I just added to the answer.

Comment: ah. i only have express installed here maybe that has something to do with it? I will try later with a propper vs install

Comment: isn't there something similar to @watch from vue ts? using the fancy `get property() {}` from ES6?